Updating a Azure IoT Central device cloud property via REST API
What is the correct API to update Azure IoT central device could properties via REST API?
I am building an automated process that adjusts cloud properties of a particular device based on external caclulations.
I inititally assumed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/dataplane/devices/update-properties?view=rest-iotcentral-dataplane-2022-07-31&tabs=HTTP would work, but either it does not work with cloud properties, or maybe I have not cracked the correct syntax. { "propertyName": "value" } did not work, { "$cloudProperties": { "propertyName": "value" } } (what you use in the IoT central web UI) also did not work.
Speaking of, the web UI uses a graphql mutation named UpdateDeviceTwinData to persist coud property changes. That led me to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/service/devices/update-twin?view=rest-iothub-service-2021-11-30#twinproperties - however, updates sent there also did not seem to work :(

The first syntax you tried should work - the device I'm using here has two cloud properties: manufacturer and targetTemperature:
dominic [ ~ ]$ az rest --method get --uri https://$appName.azureiotcentral.com/api/devices/24mfzp56bya/properties?api-version=2022-07-31 --headers Authorization="$operatorToken" "Content-Type=application/json"
{
  "manufacturer": "Contoso",
  "targetTemperature": 56
}
dominic [ ~ ]$ az rest --method patch --uri https://$appName.azureiotcentral.com/api/devices/24mfzp56bya/properties?api-version=2022-07-31 --headers Authorization="$operatorToken" "Content-Type=application/json" --body '{"targetTemperature" : 75.3}'
{
  "manufacturer": "Contoso",
  "targetTemperature": 75.3
}

Are your cloud properties defined in the "root" interface of your device template? If not, you might need to adjust the payload to reference the correct location.
